# Symfony long response time

Tags: php, apache, symfony, xampp

First of all, i looked at all previous questins conserning this subject. But neither did solve the problem.

Symfony 2.7.2 in production enviorement is giving me slow response time (0.8-2 seconds) and for development env it's from 2.6-5sec . I am aiming at a response time from 100-350ms . I've set the following:

- disabled xdebug (it's gone)
- enabled APC
- optimized autoloader (composer dump-autoload --optimize)
- checked if I'm using only IP addresses

**UPDATE**

**php.ini settings:**

- realpath_cache_size = 4096
- realpath_cache_ttl = 7200
- open_basedir = none

**Web profiler** shows the following ( cannot upload images yet ):
Initialization time is 1sec and twig is 0.8sec. Since this is in dev mode, we can ignore the twig since it will get cached in prod.

Application is an restAPI, but helpers that force profiler to show don't work. I know that dev env is slow by nature, but productio should be much faster as i saw from others using it.

Running on Windows 8.1 localhost XAMPP enviorement with php -v 5.6.8 .

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.7.6"
}
```

Comment: What's your `realpath_cache_size` in phpini? Try to set it to 2048k

Comment: realpath_cache_size = 4096 currently . Changing to 16384 or lower does not effect at all. Except that it gets longer responses.

Comment: Then you need to profile your app to check what exactly takes so long http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: do you have any other app running on the machine? is it running faster? All of your setting seems normal, I am thinking it's your machine/server setup problem...

Comment: This was a long time question, in the end it was an issue with the machine. Really strange case, not sure why it was slow at all.